# error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive

Tags: typescript, ts-migrate

Last week I used `ts-migrate` to migrate our codebase to TypeScript. The tool adds a lot of `// @ts-expect-error` comments in TS files to get it to pass the TS compiler and type checking. However, when I run `yarn run tsc` to type check my codebase I get 5k+ errors stating `error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.` Am I missing a piece of config stating that these types of errors are okay? Looking for any advice to get this to pass TS compiler.

Here is my TS config for reference.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2016",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],           
        "allowJs": true,                    
        "checkJs": false,                   
        "jsx": "react",                     
        "declaration": false,                  
        "declarationMap": false,               
        "sourceMap": false,                    
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noEmit": true,                        
        "isolatedModules": true,               
        "strict": false, 
        "noImplicitAny": false,                 
        "strictNullChecks": false,              
        "strictFunctionTypes": false,           
        "strictBindCallApply": false,           
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,  
        "noImplicitThis": false,                
        "alwaysStrict": false,                  
        "noUnusedLocals": false,                
        "noUnusedParameters": false,            
        "noImplicitReturns": false,             
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,    
        "baseUrl": "./",                       
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types/",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ], 
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    }
}
```

Full example error message:

```
src/WorkspacePicker/__tests__/index.test.tsx:27:1 - error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.

27 // @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2582) FIXME: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to instal... Remove this comment to see the full error message
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/WorkspacePicker/__tests__/index.test.tsx:29:3 - error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.

29   // @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2582) FIXME: Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install ty... Remove this comment to see the full error message
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/WorkspacePicker/__tests__/index.test.tsx:38:5 - error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.

38     // @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2304) FIXME: Cannot find name 'expect'.
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

I succeed to remove all `error TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.`

**Solution**:

Make sure you start from scratch with `ts-migrate`, then follow those steps:

1. Unfortunately, `ts-migrate` does not get updated as fast as `typescript`. So first thing to do is to check [the typescript version currently used](https://github.com/airbnb/ts-migrate/blob/master/package.json#L47) by `ts-migrate`. In my case I had to rollback Typescript from `5.x.x` to `4.7.2`
2. Install most important `@types/xxxx` libraries, such as:

   - `@types/jest`
   - `@types/node`
   - `@types/react`
   - `@types/react-dom`
3. Run `ts-migrate` specific command:

   - `yarn ts-migrate -- rename .` (this transforms js/x -> ts/x + create the `tsconfig.json` file)
4. In your `tsconfig.json` (being generated by `ts-migrate`), make sure you have those attributes:

   - If you're using jest:

   ```
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
   ```

   - The ts config runs in specific desired path(s), in my case `src`:

   ```
    "include": ["src"]
   ```
5. Run this `ts-migrate` command:

   - `yarn ts-migrate migrate`
6. Check TS errors:
   a. In my `package.json`, I added this script:

   ```
   "checkTs": "tsc --noEmit",
   ```

   b. when running `yarn checkTs`, you might have some errors. Fix them if it's not related to the `Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive` issue (because `ts-migrate` does break the code in some particular case, still rare scenario though)
7. Run `yarn ts-migrate reignore .` this will re-compute what `ts-migrate` did before and hopefully clean remaining mistakes from previous wave
8. Running again `tsc --noEmit` to check errors, you should be to `0`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my error also showed up on those non-test files. I think it is because there is a typescript version mismatch for `ts-migrate` and your IDE. I fixed it by adding a typescript package into `package.json`, to make both verisons the same

Comment: I was using a pre-commit task that ran `tsc ...` and it was failing, even though the IDE showed the error if I removed the comment. I changed the pre-commit script to `pnpm exec tsc...` and it worked :) <- I'm using `pnpm` for package management, so change the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue, had to restart my IDE (VS Code) after setting the configuration in tsconfig.json, and then it picked up on the new changes.

Comment: This is not happening only in IDEs, but in commands too.

Answer (score -7):

Simple answer. You used `// @ts-expect-error` where is no error. I recommend replace it in VS Code via regex `\s*\/\/\s*@ts-expect-error` (to nothing) to delete all of comments.

Comment: Not sure that's it because the error messages are there. I'll update the question with an example.

Comment: Okay, I take part of that back. The tests don't need to be compiled here so I see what you're saying. Let me try removing all of these from the test files.

Comment: So it looks like this is correct but I do need some of the @ts-expect-error directives. I wish there was a way for VS Code to tell you this and just remove them all but I don't think that's possible.